# I cant use sendgrid . I cant send the email

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, sendgrid

> code to send the email

```
const message = {
to: 'ayelenwf@gmail.com',
from : 'ayee_01@live.com',
subject: 'hola, estoy probando',
text: 'como va todo?',
html:'<h1>holis</h1>'
}
------------------------------------------------
sgMail.send(message)
.then((response) => console.log('email sent...')).
catch((err)=>console.log(err, 'error'))
```

[the error,  link image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdc2I.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at the [documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/quickstart-nodejs/).

1. First you must verify your sender identity in the SendGrid console.  That's usually done through DNS verification for domain-wide identities, or by answering a verification email for email address-specific senders.
2. Then, you create your SendGrid API key.  You should make sure your key remains private and is restricted to email-sending only, unless your application needs more features.
3. SendGrid provides sample code for sending emails.  Here it is:

```
    const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
    sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
    const msg = {
      to: 'test@example.com', // Change to your recipient
      from: 'test@example.com', // Change to your verified sender
      subject: 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun',
      text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
      html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
    }
    sgMail
      .send(msg)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('Email sent')
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
      })
```

[Check in the docs for more info.](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/quickstart-nodejs/)